# ORDER BY previous element id = parent_id

Tags: mysql, sql, parent-child, sql-order-by

I'm trying to build a chained list of items, in which the first one has a parent_id = 0, while the other ones should be sorted by what the last element's id was related to its parent_id.

This is the expected result:

```
| id | parent_id |
|----|-----------|
| 9  | 0         |
| 2  | 9         |
| 3  | 2         |
| 14 | 3         |
| 5  | 14        |
```

How can I do this kind of ORDER BY clause? Currently I'm at

```
parent_id = 0 desc, parent_id desc
```

But the output of this is wrong, of course, because it doesn't depend on the last ID, it's just running a desc ordering of parent_id:

```
| id | parent_id |
|----|-----------|
| 9  | 0         |
| 5  | 14        |
| 2  | 9         |
| 14 | 3         |
| 3  | 2         |
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's the first table of the post - I added a remark on it so it's less confusing. Thanks.

Comment: No. Now it's more confusing. In order to deduce output, it's useful to see input.

Comment: My current attempt - parent_id = 0 desc, COALESCE(id, parent_id), id seems to be working for this set of results. I'm trying to match a few edge cases just to be sure. Does it seem fine to you?

Comment: You might need a recursive query: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16513418/how-to-do-the-recursive-select-query-in-mysql

Comment: You are looking for a MySQL equivalent of Oracle's `CONNECT BY PRIOR`. This answer will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19132608/is-there-a-connect-by-alternative-in-mysql

Comment: @CodeNewbie pretty cool, I didn't know that. I think my current order by clause solves the issue, but thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

Ordering by:

```
'parent_id = 0 desc, COALESCE(id, parent_id), id'
```

seems to have fixed my scenario.